# UIImageView not respecting constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, constraints

Basically I am not using storyboard for anything and trying to create this all programmatically. I am trying to put an image as a banner on the top of the UIView using a UIImageView. The picture shows the results.

The white rectangle is about twice as long as what you see. I have its contentMode set to scaleAspectFit and I think the scaling up is pushing it away from the left side? When I create a label it works properly, I just have issues like this when scaling using aspect ratio.

**EDIT: Added the rest of my classes because as Evgeniy pointed out it is probably how I am setting my main view. Maybe because how I am setting my controllers self as the mainView in the property?**

```
class MainView:UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = .green

    setupViews()
    setupConstraints()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews()
{
    self.addSubview(banner)

    let label = UILabel(frame: self.frame)
    label.text = "HELLO WORLD"

    self.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
}

func setupConstraints()
{
    let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    banner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    banner.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    banner.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    banner.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: (screenSize.height/5) + 10).isActive = true
    banner.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}

let banner: UIImageView = {
    let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let image = UIImage(named: "serveBanner")
    let iView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:screenSize.width, height:(screenSize.height/5)))
    iView.clipsToBounds = true
    iView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    iView.image = image
    return iView
}()
```

}

MainViewController

```
import UIKit
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

var mainView:MainView {return self.view as! MainView }
var buttonClicked = false
private let navigator: MainNavigator

init(navigator: MainNavigator)
{
    self.navigator = navigator
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func loadView()
{
    self.view = MainView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
}

private func buttonAction()
{
    navigator.navigate(to: .PipingSealsApp)
}
}
```

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let navController = UINavigationController()
    let mainNavigator = MainNavigator(navigationController: navController)
    let mainViewController = MainViewController(navigator: mainNavigator)
    navController.setViewControllers([mainViewController], animated: false)
    window?.rootViewController = navController

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
}
```

[image: Code Results]

Comment: Screenshots like what you posted really aren;'t helpful, so I'm not enlarging it. Are you "respecting" `contentMode ? Dealing with it? If not, PLEASE - paste into the question code (not a screenshot) that we can possibly duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: Don't really appreciate the downvote because you don't like a screenshot as that isn't helping my question get answered. I will also add code blocks for those of you who want that. As for contentMode it is set to scaleAspectFit. So I am thinking it is scaling away from the left edge but I don't know how to tell it to stick to the left edge other than constraints.

Comment: show us your image  ?

Answer (score 1):

So after digging knowing that it should have worked I made another test bed and found the solution. It was actually just something stupid but people should be aware of it. This code should have the `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` removed.

```
func setupConstraints(){
let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
banner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
banner.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
banner.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
banner.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: (screenSize.height/5) + 10).isActive = true
banner.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

Should read

```
func setupConstraints(){
let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

banner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
banner.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
banner.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
banner.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: (screenSize.height/5) + 10).isActive = true
banner.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

I am not completely sure why this is happening but I will read up on the property and see if I can make sense of it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I've found something similar. If `self` is the `UIViewContoller.view` or it's root view, it seems setting the auto resize mask to false can screw up the subviews. There *are* times I use it on the root view, but rarely (and not as a rule). To be honest? I'm not sure why, but my *guess* is it has to do with `UIWindow` or `UIScreen`, both of which *probably* don't use anything in the OS. Glad you figured out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried you code without any modifications (well, except for image name), and got this:
[image]

Is that what you are trying to achieve?
If yes, then may be the problem is in how you add your main view onto view controller?
Here's my code, please compare:

```
let mainView = MainView(frame: self.view.bounds)
mainView.backgroundColor = .green
self.view.addSubview(mainView)

mainView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
mainView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: In case of navigationBar, the top and bottom anchor could be `mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true` and `mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: Thanks for the info! I still find it odd that the text label will find the right constraints but the UIImageView does not? I have added my other classes to help give more insight. I am creating a UINavigationController and adding my ViewController as its first element. In the view controller I set a property to return my MainView as self.view. This may be the issue?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem finally. It is really got broken with navigation controller. 
Remove this line
`self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
from `setupConstraints()`, and you should be fine.
I can only assume, but cannot confidently explain why it happens. It would be great, if someone clarified this.

Comment: Yeah I found the same thing. I would love to understand why it is happening also. The oddest part was the Label performed normally and yet the Image did not. So not only did it cause something to go wrong but it was inconsistent. This makes me think it is a bug.